# fliend createdAt in Prisma schema returns a null value when createUser() is called

Tags: mongodb, graphql, prisma

When including a createdAt field in my datamodel.prisma schema the DateTime! returns a null value.

I am raising this on here so that if anyone else has the same problem, hopefully they will be able to find this post.

// in datamodel.prisma

type User {
    id: ID! @id
    trade_no: String!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    createdAt: DateTime!
}

Error message looks like this "Reason: 'createdAt' Expected non-null value, found null."

Answer (score 1):

In mongoDB the createdAt must be written as

type User {
    id: ID! @id
    trade_no: String!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    **created_at: DateTime! @createdAt**
}

when used with Prisma (don't know if this is the case for other databases). Also, bear in mind that the @relation directive must have **link: INLINE** as an argument (the relationship is stored in the record, not in a separate table). Took me a while to work this out so I thought I'd put it here.

It's worth having a look at https://www.prisma.io/docs/releases-and-maintenance/features-in-preview/mongodb-b6o5/ for other specificities with Prisma & mongoDB.

Comment: Also, note that these features are not specific to Mongo but rather part of the datamodel 1.1 spec which is in beta right now. Please have a look here: https://github.com/prisma/datamodel-v1.1-feedback